# Data dissapeared in input field values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Html table inside .cshtml file.But when i hardcoded values it shows me but when i get those values from the foreach loop,table  dissapeared

```html
<script>
    var nTable = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        @foreach (var item in Model.NewsModel)
        {
            @:nTable = "<tr class=\"news1\">";
            @:nTable += "<td>";
            @:nTable += "<input id=\"test1\" value="+ item.NewsNo +" class=\"form-control\" />";// This is not working / item.NewsNo has a value.
            @:nTable += "<input id=\"test1\" value=\"Helloooo\" class=\"form-control\" />";// This is  working with hardcoded values
            @:nTable += "<td>";
            @:nTable += "</tr>";
        }
        document.getElementById('GlobeNews').innerHTML = nTable;
    });
</script>

<div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading"><u><b>Total News</b></u></div>
    <div class="panel-body utiDIv">
        <table id="GlobeNews">
            <tr></tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If `item.NewsNo` has spaces you'll need to include quotes around the attribute value: `value=\"" + item.NewsNo + "\"`. Also, you're duplicating the `id` on every row. They need to be unique

Comment: What is the reason for building the `<table>` with a script?

Comment: where is the <table> element?

Comment: @KurioZ7 OP Updated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have tried your change.but still there's no any progreee

Comment: What is the value of `item.NewsNo`? Also, as @StephenMuecke has alluded to, it's very odd to build HTML via JS via C#. You can just add the HTML directly and then use Razor to add the required values

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  item.NewsNo is a number like 1000

Comment: you could try `var newsModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.NewsModel));` and use `newsModel` to iterate. but I really didn't understand why create this in a script

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have null values in NewsNo. I suggest you better way to do this is to include loop in html instead of adding to js code. Try this:

```
<div class="panel panel-success">
<div class="panel-heading"><u><b>Total News</b></u></div>
<div class="panel-body utiDIv">
    <table id="GlobeNews">
        @foreach (var item in Model.NewsModel)
        {
            <tr class="news1">
                <td>
                    <input id="test1" value="@item.NewsNo" class="form-control" />
                    <input id="test1" value="Helloooo" class="form-control" />
                <td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

</div>
```